# Load an assembly at run time that references the calling assembly

Tags: c#, reference, assemblies, runtime

My application loads all library assemblies located in its executing path and executes preknown methods against contained classes.

I now need to do the same with an assembly that references my application assembly. Is this possible and are there any negative implications that I should be aware of?

Master Assembly:

```
public abstract class TaskBase 
{ 
    public abstract void DoWork(); 
}  

LoadAssemblyFromFile("Assembly0001.dll");  
Assembly0001.Task1.DoWork();
```

Child Assemblies:

```
public sealed class Task1: MasterAssembly.TaskBase  
{ 
    public override void DoWork { /* whatever */ } 
}
```

Comment: I do this all of the time without any problems. The only gotcha that I've run into (a few times actually) is version management of the _master_ assembly. If you make changes to the _master_ without recompiling the children you can run into some bizarre problems.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Thanks. Out of curiosity, what kind of problems? I do not auto-increment assembly versions on recompile. I am presuming that SHOULD bypass whatever issues you may have encountered. Your thoughts?

Comment: The most common problem I've encountered is that a method definition changes breaking backward compatibility, though in other cases I've experienced the dreaded "_Type_ is defined in both _Master_ and _Master_" exception (from memory so not literal text, but close enough that you'll recognize it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. As long as your master assembly doesn't reference the child assemblies, you should be fine. Otherwise, you'll have a circular dependency.

The master assembly will simply load the child assemblies and know nothing about them except that they implement an interface. That way, the master assembly doesn't need to reference the child assemblies.

No gotchas as far as I'm aware. We use this technique successfully for certain scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. Out of context, is there a way to load assemblies from memory without the assembly file being present on disk? These periodic assembly releases are present in a central database and I would prefer to make it reasonably difficult for users to get their hands on. Of course, I understand there is no fool-proof way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, we had mobile apps like that. The assembly binary was stored in the database, retrieved and loaded that way. You could do the same thing.

Comment: Found it: Assembly.Load(byte[]).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there is nothing wrong with this.  In fact, [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) uses this technique in the form of `AssemblyCatalog` (where your implementations are IN the master assembly) and `DirectoryCatalog` (where the implementations of an interface are in assemblies in a specific directory).

Both can be used together in an `AggregateCatalog` with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The only "problem" is that you can't write Assembly0001.Task1 in your Master assembly but you can find the correct task in the loaded assembly and invoke that one:

```
var asm = LoadAssemblyFromFile("Assembly0001.dll");
var taskType = asm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(TaskBase).IsAssignableFrom(t));
var task = (TaskBase)Activator.CreateInstance(taskType);
task.DoWork();
```

You'll still need to add some extra safety checks :)

Comment: Yes, of course. Creating a run time instance by type is the only way to achieve this. What kind of security checks would you recommend? The application does need to make sure that it is executing our own code (possibly through a one-way hash). What else?

Comment: Well mostly just null checks, if you really want to create a sandbox for running your tasks it can become a little more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post code of your LoadAssemblyFromFile("...") method, but if it uses Assembly.LoadFrom() or Assembly.LoadFile() to loads assemblies, you could get InvalidCastException, MissingMethodException or other exceptions, especially if your application and loaded assembly both references identical other assembly. LoadFrom() and LoadFile() loades assemblies in different binding context than your application is in. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) for detailed explanation.